# Pandas dataframe: optimize performance of new feature engineering

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, optimization, feature-engineering

I have a bikesharing trip dataset with these four columns:

- start_time (datetime)
- end_time (datetime)
- start_station_id (int)
- end_station_id (int)

Now I want to create a new feature called 'idle_time'.
It is about the idle time of a particular station after a trip - the timeframe from when a trip ended at a particular station until another trip starts at this station.

So for each row x 'idle_time' is defined by:

start_time of the first record y (in a dataframe sorted by start_time) matching these conditions:

```
y.start_station == x.end_station
AND
y.start_time >= x.end_time
```

So this is the solution I ended up with and it is working correctly but it is insane slow.

I already did research and I read a lot about vectorization but I just don't see how I can take advantage of vectorization in this specific case.

I tested the code on a small testset with correct results but on my large dataset (3.5 million records) it is not finishing.

```
def get_next_start_time(row):
    filtered_column=df[np.logical_and((df['start_station_id']==row.end_station_id), (df['start_time']>=row.end_time))]['start_time']
    if len(filtered_column)>0:
        return filtered_column.iat[0]
    else:
        return pd.NaT

df['end_station_next_start_time'] = df.apply(get_next_start_time,axis=1)

df['idle_time'] = df['end_station_next_start_time'] - df['end_time']
```